# Highly Available PostgreSQL with patroni

Tags: postgresql, high-availability

I follow this guide to set up an lab for postgres HA

https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-highly-available-postgresql-cluster-using-patroni-on-ubuntu-16-04_594477

I follow exactly the guide (change the ip address in my case), after all it all work though on postgres server 1

But when come to postgres server 2 `patroni.yml` setup

The guide said on both postgres server have the same `patroni.yml` setup, but when restart the `patroni service`

This problems happened
server1

```
quanlm@DB1:~$ sudo service patroni status
● patroni.service - Runners to orchestrate a high-availability PostgreSQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/patroni.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-11-12 07:35:33 UTC; 14min ago
 Main PID: 411 (patroni)
    Tasks: 12
   Memory: 77.6M
      CPU: 4.041s
   CGroup: /system.slice/patroni.service
           ├─411 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/patroni /etc/patroni.yml
           ├─431 postgres -D /data/patroni --config-file=/data/patroni/postgresql.conf --listen_addresses=192.168.122.77 --max_prepared_tran
           ├─435 postgres: postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                   
           ├─436 postgres: postgres: writer process                                                                                         
           ├─439 postgres: postgres: stats collector process                                                                                
           ├─447 postgres: postgres: postgres postgres 192.168.122.77(49984) idle                                                           
           ├─455 postgres: postgres: wal writer process                                                                                     
           └─456 postgres: postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                            

Nov 12 07:49:28 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:49:28,533 INFO: no action.  i am the leader with the lock
Nov 12 07:49:38 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:49:38,459 INFO: Lock owner: postgresql0; I am postgresql0
Nov 12 07:49:38 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:49:38,536 INFO: no action.  i am the leader with the lock
Nov 12 07:49:48 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:49:48,459 INFO: Lock owner: postgresql0; I am postgresql0
Nov 12 07:49:48 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:49:48,544 INFO: no action.  i am the leader with the lock
Nov 12 07:49:58 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:49:58,458 INFO: Lock owner: postgresql0; I am postgresql0
Nov 12 07:49:58 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:49:58,548 INFO: no action.  i am the leader with the lock
Nov 12 07:50:08 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:50:08,457 INFO: Lock owner: postgresql0; I am postgresql0
Nov 12 07:50:08 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:50:08,539 INFO: no action.  i am the leader with the lock
Nov 12 07:50:19 DB1 patroni[411]: 2019-11-12 07:50:19,949 INFO: acquired session lock as a leader
```

Yeah server 1 was fine but on server 2

```
quanlm@DB2:~$ sudo service patroni status
● patroni.service - Runners to orchestrate a high-availability PostgreSQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/patroni.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-11-12 07:50:02 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 9514 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/patroni /etc/patroni.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9514 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 patroni[9514]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 440, in __init__
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 patroni[9514]:     self.server_bind()
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 patroni[9514]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 patroni[9514]:     socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 patroni[9514]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 454, in server_bind
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 patroni[9514]:     self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 patroni[9514]: OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 systemd[1]: patroni.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 systemd[1]: patroni.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 12 07:50:02 DB2 systemd[1]: patroni.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It not working after all.

I have allow remote connect for both server by edit `listen_addresses = '*'` on `postgresql.conf` and

`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5`

on `pg_hba.conf`

So when HAproxy go to work, when the 1st down, the 2nd server didn't go up.

The problems is surely on the `patroni` on server 2 but how to fix it?

Otherwise, are there any way around to HA postgresql server?

P/s: firewall settings

```
quanlm@DB1:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
quanlm@DB1:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

```
quanlm@DB2:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
quanlm@DB2:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log it looks like you need to execute on the second server:

```
# systemctl enable patroni.service
# systemctl start patroni.service
```

I deduce this because the error message says that it's disabled. (I use Postgres a lot but haven't tried patroni yet.)

Comment: tks but that not how it fixed
What do you use to HA postgres ?

Comment: @LêMinhQuân Postgres doesn't need much help to be "high-availability." As part of what I do, I design - "Architect" - systems for people, and have done so since the mid 1990s. Postgres' replication - especially "cascading replication" added in a late version 9,x - lets you do a split read / write. The company I work for was the first to create split read/write database library, where the library knows to send writes to the master and fetch reads from a "slave" ("replicant"). If you're aware of your application's design, a sharp architect can design the database to match with super-high "HA".

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Patroni, but the log is pretty clear about the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Not sure about the involved architecture, but in case you've configured some sort of "floating IP" which clients use to connect, then this IP is assigned to only one of your nodes. If you want Patroni to use this address on the second node as well, one way to deal with this problem is to allow to bind to "non-local" IPs (which is disabled by default, leading to the above error).

To accomplish this, set

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

via `sysctl`.

(Please note: As written, I've never used Patroni. You have to check for yourself, if the stuff I wrote makes sense and does fit your environment.)

Comment: Tks for your help but that not the problems, so what do you use to setup HA for postgres ?

Comment: @gf_ Good catch! Somehow I overlooked, "OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address" Oops!

Comment: @LêMinhQuân Sorry, I'm unable to follow: "but that not the problems". In fact, my answer deals specifically with the problem you reported in your question. I can't help any further, I'm afraid. Regarding your second question: I've used (in the past, no need currently) `corosync`, `pacemaker`, and some `resource agents`. If you want to setup a HA PostgreSQL cluster, ensure you set up proper `fencing` aka `STONITH`.